# Is there a way to automate changes in saturation/levels for 300 different batches in Photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

Alright, so I have 300 folders. Each folder contains several images.

For each folder, I want to change both the saturation and levels (Photoshop) of all the images within. Each folder needs different saturation and levels.

I am aware that I can use a Photoshop action to batch process all the images inside one folder. However, I will would have to customize it 300 times since there are 300 folders (each needing different parameters).

I already know the values I want to use. I can supply them in pretty much any format (a text file, a csv, etc etc it doesn't matter).

So the problem is basically the fact that, even using actions, I would have to create 300 different actions in Photoshop.

I can code something in Java that can process the images automatically, but for one reason or another, it seems Photoshop has different (preferred) results.

Is there a way to automate changes in saturation/levels for 300 runs in Photoshop?

I have both Mac OSX Yosemite and Windows 7. Doesn't really matter to me which platform.

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript, the answer is no.

However, I know you can batch edit files within Adobe Bridge. I'd give that a shot, specially for a simple function like changing saturation.